# working with nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I think this is silly question and simple but I can't find any result in google and other resource

I have array of object like this

```
 const myArr = [
     [{
         id: 1,
         price: 200,
     }, {
         id: 2,
         price: 900,
     }, {
         id: 3,
         price: 100,
     }],
     [{
         id: 5,
         price: 100,
     }]
 ];
```

In other word I have an array and my array contain some array and each of inner array contain some object inside them

```
 arr [ [ {},{},{} ] ,   [ {} ]    ]
```

now I want get two thing

1. count of all products ?
2. sum of all products ?

*(each object = one product)

Comment: Could you show the code you have tried, please?

Answer (score 4):

Flatten to a single array by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the `sum`.

The `count` is flattened array's length.

```js
const myArr = [[{"id":1,"price":200},{"id":2,"price":900},{"id":3,"price":100}],[{"id":5,"price":100}]];

const flattened = [].concat(...myArr);
const count = flattened.length;
const sum = flattened.reduce((s, o) => s + o.price, 0);

console.log('count', count);
console.log('sum', sum);
```

Comment: @OriDrori, we have same ideas but you was faster. Anyway, thumbs up and upvote.

Comment: @OriDrori my friend , now i have another question about this , you think every product have property { count : n  } 

and this means the count of each products 
now how can i get sum price  ??

Comment: @OriDrori , for example => [ [ { id:1 , price:100 , count:10 } ] , [ { id:2 , price:200 , count:5 } ] ];

i want this result

(price of product)100 * (count of product)10 .  .......

Comment: You actually have the answer. Look at the `sum` calculation in my code...

Comment: can u give me more details

Comment: You want to add to the sum price * count - how would you change - `s + o.price` to fit what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concat` to wrap all objects within one single `array`.

Apply `length` property in order to find out the number of objects in the array and then `reduce` method to get the sum.

```js
const myArr = [ [ { id:1, price:200, }, { id:2, price:900, }, { id:3, price:100, } ], [ { id:5, price:100, } ] ];

arr = myArr.reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr), []);
sum = arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price, 0);
console.log('count ' + arr.length);
console.log('sum ' + sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread to flat the array:

```js
var myArr = [
 [
   { 
     id:1,
     price:200,
   },

   { 
     id:2,
     price:900,
   },

   { 
     id:3,
     price:100,
   }
 ],

[
  { 
     id:5,
     price:100,
   }
]
];

var arr = [].concat(...myArr);
console.log('Length: ', arr.length);
var sum = arr.reduce((m, o) => m + o.price, 0);
console.log('Sum: ', sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

## ES6

You can also use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method of array to get the required result

> [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can be used to iterate through the array, adding the current element value to the sum of the previous element values.

**DEMO**

```js
const myArr = [[{id: 1,price: 200,}, {id: 2,price: 900,}, {id: 3,price: 100,}],[{id: 5,price: 100,}]];
  
let result = myArr.reduce((r,v)=>{
  r.count += v.length;
  r.sum += v.reduce((total,{price}) => total+price,0);
  return r;
},{count:0,sum:0}) 

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```